# Why is this multivariate $3\sigma$ ellipse rotated?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

While reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/838333/17974), I clicked on the provided link to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). The [main article image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MultivariateNormal.png) shows the PDF of a 2D multivariate normally distributed system:

[image]

In the image, the $3\sigma$ ellipse is marked in green. Since the two variable coordinates x and y are normally (and thus symmetrically) distributed around the X and Y axes, I'd expect the ellipse's major and minor axes to be aligned with the X and Y axes. The image shows a slightly rotated ellipse.

Why is the ellipse rotated? Is it just a drawing error?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @HansLundmark - where is this limitation mentioned in the article? Or, is it just your *possible* explanation to the rotation of the ellipe?

Comment: @ysap - Although it is not explicitly stated in the Wikipedia, it does appear that @HansLundmark is correct. The random variables are not independent. 

If you are familiar with R, then run the following:

`install.packages('mvtnorm')`
`require(mvtnorm)`
`#Sample from multivariate normal distribution of independent random variables`
`obs <- rmvnorm(n = 10000, mean = c(0, 0), sigma = matrix(data = c(10, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2))`
`plot(x = obs[, 1], y = obs[, 2], xlim = c(-15, 15), ylim = c(-15, 15))`

Comment: @Jubbles - I am not familiar w/ R, however, I don't need that code to realize that dependent variables can rotate the ellipse. An extreme case is when x = y, so the ellipse is reduced to a 45deg straight line.

Comment: @HansLundmark -  OK, I'll take it that this is the cause for the rotation in the image. If you make this an answer, I'll up-vote it.

Comment: All right, I wrote an answer (with a little explanation too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. As you can tell from the following line in the source code on the image page, there is a correlation between them:

```
CovMatrix = [1 0.6; 0.6 2];
```

(The off-diagonal entries in the covariance matrix are non-zero.)

Comment: Where do you see the source code??

Comment: In the image description the OP mentions "Matlab code provided below.", but I see no code (nor in the 4 other pages where this image appear).

Comment: On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMultivariateNormal.png, I just scroll down. It's between "Summary" and "Licensing".

Comment: mm... I noticed that Wikipedia changed their interface some time ago. Now when I click on the image I get an "active" page, showing the image on a black background, with some dynamic info strip at the bottom. How did you get to that "static" page?

Comment: Looks like they call this thing "Media Viewer"

Comment: OK, I think I found it here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Multimedia/Media_Viewer/Help#How_can_I_bypass_Media_Viewer.3F

Comment: Every day you learn something new ;-) Thanks.

Comment: I just opened it in a new tab (like I usually do). And if I click on the link in my comment above, I get the static page.