# Generate Random Sparse Vectors at a Given Distance on the Unit Hypersphere

Tags: geometry, vectors, python

I'm trying to write a Python function that would take 3 parameters:
n: Number of dimensions
s: Sparsity factor (example 0.9)
d: Distance

The function would return two vectors in n dimensions that are on the unit hypersphere at distance "d" and they are both sparse.

The distance can be euclidean (0..2) or angular (0..Pi) it doesn't matter.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Luis.

Comment: By "sparsity factor" do you mean something like "the fraction of entries that are non-zero"? Do you want these vectors to be chosen "randomly"? If so, with respect to what probability measure on the sphere?

Comment: I meant the sparsity factor as the fraction of zeros, but it doesn't matter which way you take it. Either 90% of zeros or 10% of zeros is the same for the application, you just put the number you need to use.

Comment: And I would like the vectors to be uniformly random on the unit hypersphere.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly select the members you wish to be non-zero:

```
from random import random, gauss

n = 1000
s = 0.1
d = 10 # distance between two points
non_zero = []
for i in range(n):
    if random() < s:
        non_zero.append(i)
```

Then sample a point on the sphere in `len(non_zero)` dimensions ([see mathoverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585996/92108)).

```
v = [gauss() for i in non_zero]
mag = sum(x**2 for x in v)**(0.5)
v = [x / mag for x in v]
```

Put it back into the original space

```
w = [0 for _ in range(d)]
for i, x in zip(non_zero, v):
    w[i] = x
print w
```

We now need a point $z$ which satisfies

- $|z| = 1$
- $|z - w| = d$
- $z$ is sparse.

Retraction:

I am leaving this partial solution because it might help someone else. But this problem doesn't seem amenable to generating one point, then the second. If $d$ is really small (and we are considering Euclidean distances), then the second vector must be non-zero in every coordinate where the first, ruining its sparseness. If $d$ is angular and small, then $\frac{w \cdot z}{|w||z|} = w \cdot z = \cos(d)$ is nearly 1, and the non-zero coordinates of $w$ must be non-zero in $z$ as well.

Edits:

- Added distance $d = 10$.
- Changed variable names to agree with OP's.
- Removed scaling $w$
- Added Retract.

Comment: This creates a single point in the sphere, I need two random points at a given distance.

Comment: @user3635284 do you need two points on the sphere? Then run it twice. Are you looking for two points which for an equilateral triangle with the origin?

Comment: As I understand the OP, distance to the origin = 1  (since they are in the unit hypersphere), parameter d is distance *between* the vectors.