# Given a vector $v$ and an angle $\theta$, find a vector $w$ such that the angle between $v$ and $w$ is exactly $\theta$

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, angle

Given:

- an $n$-dimensional vector $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$
- an angle $\theta \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

I am looking for a technique to construct a vector $w = (w_1,\ldots, w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$$\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\|\|w\|} = \cos(\theta)$$

I am specifically interested in a way to do this for $n > 3$ dimensions (for $n \leq 3$, I think you could do it with rotation matrices).

I realize that when $n \geq 3$, there are an infinite number of feasible vectors $w$. I would be OK with any $w$ that satisfies the following criteria:

1. $v$ and $w$ are distinct: $v_i \neq w_i$ for all $i$.
2. all components of $w$ are non-zero: $w_i \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: How do you define the angle in $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: How would you satisfy your criteria if $v = (1,0,0)$ and $\theta = \pi/ 2$ ?

Comment: @Youem I don't have an intuitive definition for the angle in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It should just be any vector $w$ such that the cosine similarity is $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: okay I understand your definition of the angle but you criteria is not always doable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "just wing it" algorithm which I think would be numerically stable is

- Find a nonzero vector $u$ that is perpendicular to $v$, for example
  $$ u=(0,\ldots,0,v_j,0,\ldots,0,-v_i,0,\ldots,0)$$
  where $v_i$ and $v_j$ are the numerically largest coordinates of $v$.
- Normalize $u$ so its norm equals $\|v\|$.
- Take $w=\cos(\theta)v+\sin(\theta)u$.

Note that $w$ does not depend continuously on $v$, but that is impossible when $n$ is odd, due to the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). For even $n$ you can get continuity by taking
$$ u = (v_2,-v_1,v_4,-v_3,\ldots) $$

---

If it's important to you to make all elements of $w$ nonzero, instead choose all elements of $u$ except one *randomly* (with some continuous distribution). Let the one you *don't* choose randomly correspond to the numerically largest coordinate of $v$; then you can easily solve for the value of that coordinate that will make $u\cdot v=0$.

Then each element of $ w $ will almost surely be nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another solution (credit goes to one of the PhD students in my lab), since I found it elegant / wanted to post some code for others.

---

**Solution**:

Given $v$, we want to find a $w$ such that:

$$\frac{v.w}{\|v\|\|w\|} = \cos(\theta)$$

For clarity of exposition, let's assume that $\|v\| =1$ and $\|w\| = 1$ (if $v$ is not normalized, then normalize it). We can now express our required condition as:

$$v.w = \cos(\theta)$$

We will construct a suitable vector as $$w = U.r$$ where:

- $U = [\, v \,|\, u_2 \,|\, \ldots \,|\,u_n] \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an orthonormal matrix with $v$ in the first column. We can construct this matrix given $v$ by using the Gram-Schmidt process to determine the remaining basis vectors $u_2,\ldots, u_d$.
- $r = (r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_d) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector where $r_1 = \cos(\theta)$ and $\|r\| = 1$

To see that these choices of $U$ and $r$ produce a suitable $w$, note:

$$\begin{align}
v.w &= v.(Ur)\\
&= v.(u_1.r_1 + u_2.r_2, \ldots, u_d. r_d)\\
&= (v.u_1) r_1 + (v.u_2)r_2 + \ldots + (v.u_d)r_d\\
\end{align}$$
By construction of $U$, we have that $u_1 = v$ and $v.u_i = 0$ for $i = 2,\ldots, n$, so:
$$\begin{align}
(v.u_1) r_1 + (v.u_2)r_2 + \ldots + (v.u_d)r_d = \|v\|^2 r_1 = r_1
\end{align}$$
Since we have set $r_1 = \cos(\theta)$, we therefore have that: 
$$\frac{v.w}{\|v\|\|w\|} = r_1 = \cos(\theta)$$ as desired.

Note that we are not quite done, since we still have choose $r_2,\ldots, r_d$ so that $\|r\| = 1$. This requires:
$$
\begin{align}
\|r\| &= 1\\
{r_1}^2 + {r_2}^2 + \ldots + {r_n}^2 &= 1\\
\cos^2(\theta) + {r_2}^2 + \ldots + {r_n}^2 &= 1\\
{r_2}^2 + \ldots + {r_n}^2 &= 1 - \cos^2(\theta) \\
{r_2}^2 + \ldots + {r_n}^2 &= \sin^2(\theta)
\end{align}
$$
In other words, $r_2,\ldots, r_n$ must lie on the surface of a $n$-dimensional sphere with radius $\sin(\theta)$. While there are many ways to choose these values, one easy way is to sample this point uniformly from the surface of the sphere. [Based on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585996/7145), this can be achieved by sampling a $n -1$ random variables $r_i \sim N(0,1)$ and scaling them so that their norm is exactly $\sin(\theta)$

---

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def rotate_vector(v, angle):

    """
    returns vector w such that |w|=|v| and v.w/|v||w| = cos(angle) and 
    :param v: numpy array with dimension d >= 2
    :param angle: angle of rotation in radians 
    :return: w, numpy array of dimension v.dim
    """

    assert isinstance(v, np.ndarray)
    assert np.all(np.isfinite(v)) and v.ndim == 1 and len(v) >= 2
    norm_value = norm(v)
    d = len(v)

    # normalize vector
    v = v / norm(v)

    # construct orthonormal matrix U where U[:, 0] = v
    while True:
        u_diag = np.random.randn(d)
        if not np.any(np.isclose(u_diag, 0.0, atol = 0.01)):
            break

    U = np.diag(u_diag)
    U[:, 0] = v
    U, _ = np.linalg.qr(U)
    assert np.all(np.isclose(np.abs(U[:, 0]), np.abs(v)))

    # overcases cases where U flips the sign
    if np.all(np.isclose(U[:, 0], -v)):
        U = -U

    # generate a vector r = [r_1, r_2, .., .. r_d ]
    # r = cos(angle)
    # r_2,..., r_d are any non-zero values such that (r_2)^2 + ... + (r_d)^2 = sin^2(alpha)

    # r_2,..,r_d is just a point on a d-1 dimensional sphere with radius sin(alpha)
    # this can be sampled uniformly using a multivariate gaussian
    # see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585996/7145
    while True:
        z = np.random.randn(d-1)
        if not np.any(np.isclose(z, 0.0, atol = 0.01)):
            break

    r = np.sin(angle) * (z / norm(z))
    r = np.insert(r, 0, np.cos(angle))

    # compute rotated unit vector
    w = np.dot(U, r)
    assert np.isclose(norm(w), 1.0)
    assert np.isclose(angle, np.arccos(np.dot(v, w)))

    # rescale vector with the same norm as original input
    w = w * norm_value
    return w
```